# How to restrict textbox to enter Decimal values where before decimal upto 6 digits are allowed and after decimal 2 digits

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

In windows application textbox,user can only enter decimal values where  before decimal upto 6 digits are allowed and after decimal 2 digits.(total digits cannot exceed more than 8)

--- User should be able to use Delete and Back buttons.

Examples:-

```
> Valid - 123456.22 , 12.22,.33,0.44,123.45(123456.22 - total digits 8)
> Invalid - 1234567.22,123.222,-88.99,-888.999
```

Below is the regular expression which i have used to restrict.

```
 public bool IsDecimalLimitedtoTwoDigits(string inputvalue)
        {
            Regex isnumber = new Regex(@"^[\d]{1,6}([.]{1}[\d]{1,2})?$");
            return isnumber.IsMatch(inputvalue);
        }
```

The above code works fine,when i used in Datagridview validating event as the user leaved the cell.

Now i am confused about the Textbox event to be used to use the above method.

==>  I want to restrict the user from entering wrong data.So i dont to use leave/validating events and the above Regular expression doesn't satisfy the criteria(123456.22 - total digits 8).So pls help me with the regular expression too.

Thanks,
Prathap.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Validating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating.aspx) event of `Control` and use [ErrorProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.aspx) to display validation errors.

See, for instance, [this](http://www.sellsbrothers.com/writing/winformsdatavalidation.htm) article which describes the use of them in 'Data Format Notification' section.

Comment: But the validating event will only trigger when focus moves from the control.I have used textbox validating event and it works fine with the regular expression.I want to validate, when user is entering the data.

Comment: Oh right, I understand now. Could you use `MasktedTextBox` with its `Mask` property? Regex is not supported though, you need to use the format described in here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: As regular expression is available and used in most of the places in my application, I dont want to use the maskedtextbox now.I am just wondering how to use keypress/keydown event in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

you just call your method

```
public bool IsDecimalLimitedtoTwoDigits(string inputvalue)
        {
            Regex isnumber = new Regex(@"^[\d]{1,6}([.]{1}[\d]{1,2})?$");
            return isnumber.IsMatch(inputvalue);
        }
```

in `Textbox Leave` event

or

if you have any `submit` button or `save` button , validate the code inside button click event

you can display the error message using a `MessageBox` or using an `Errorprovider` control

if you want to validate the  data when entering you have to add code in the `TextChanged` or `KeyPress` event

in key press event add

```
 if (! IsDecimalLimitedtoTwoDigits(textbox1.text)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

Comment: I have already tried this.In the above case text will be empty because for the very first time when user inputs data, only after the keypress event there will be text in the textbox.